# Can't understand how to extract post data from ejabberd http request handler

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I'm trying to get to know ejabberd and erlang...

The first thing i wan't to do is to implement my own set of REST calls to control ejabberd from another server.

for example for this request:

```
POST /custom/register HTTP/1.1
Host: some.server.com:8088
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"username":"user","host":"test.com","password":"pass1"}
```

I want to register new Jabber user, so I've created this ejabberd module:

```
-module(mod_test).

-author('').

-vsn('0.1').

-behavior(gen_mod).

-export([start/2, stop/1,process/2]).

%%
%% Includes
%%

%% base ejabberd headers
-include("ejabberd.hrl").

%% ejabberd compatibility functions
-include("jlib.hrl").

%% ejabberd HTTP headers
-include("web/ejabberd_http.hrl").

start(_Host, _Opts) ->
        ok.

stop(_Host) ->
        ok.

process(["register"], _Request) ->
        Data = _Request#request.data,
        {200,[],Data}.
```

And added the http listener in ejabberd.cfg, I've been able to get the response that contains the post data back, BUT, I cant understand how to extract the the values from the Data.

for example I want that the variable Username will get the value of the "username" key ("user") in the POST data.

Thanks in Advance,
Matan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejabberd uses [Jiffy](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy) which is an Erlang JSON parser. So you can use it to parse your HTTP request POST payload inside the handler.

**Request**

```
$ curl \
   -XPOST http://localhost:5280/test/register \
   --data '{"username":"user","host":"test.com","password":"pass1"}'
```

**Handler**

```
process([<<"register">>], #request{method = 'POST', data = Data}) ->
    {JSON} = jiffy:decode(Data),
    User = proplists:get_value(<<"username">>, JSON),
    Host = proplists:get_value(<<"host">>, JSON),
    Pass = proplists:get_value(<<"password">>, JSON),

    %% do something with:
    %% User =:= <<"user">>
    %% Host =:= <<"test.com">>
    %% Pass =:= <<"pass1">>
    %% ...

    {200, [], <<"response">>};
process(_Call, _Req) ->
    {404, [], <<"not_found">>}.
```